# Accessing s3 data locally with pyspark - trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

I want to run a pyspark session on my local machine and I want to use the data I've stored in an AWS s3 bucket. So far I'm trying to do

```
import pyspark as ps

fp = "s3n://my-bucket/some/data/file.csv"
spark = ps.sql.SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.csv(fp, schema=SCHEMA, sep="\t")
df.show(10, False)
```

where the schema is correctly defined elsewhere. However, I receive some weird warnings and a weird error: (Notice that the first part is just a warning and doesn't prevent the code from running, even if it explicitly says `java/util.ServiceConfigurationError`.)

```
2018-04-27 15:04:59 WARN  NativeCodeLoader:62 - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2018-04-27 15:05:01 WARN  FileSystem:2639 - Cannot load filesystem
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem Unable to get public no-arg constructor
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/AmazonServiceException
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException
2018-04-27 15:05:02 WARN  FileStreamSink:66 - Error while looking for metadata directory.

py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o32.csv.
: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.S3Exception: org.jets3t.service.ServiceException: Request Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
Caused by: org.jets3t.service.ServiceException: Request Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
```

What are trustAnchors? how can I solve the issue?

A funny thing is that, if I try to use `boto3` and download the same file, I can do it with no problem, which leads me to think that it's not a permission-related issue. However, downloading the entire bucket to my machine is not a viable solution because of the size of my data and the rate at which it arrives.

I've installed pyspark in a clean virtual environment using pycharm. I added the jars `aws-java-sdk-1.11.317.jar` and `hadoop-aws-2.7.3.jar` inside the `pyspark/jars` folder and [created an `hdfs-site.xml`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html#Authentication_properties) with my AWS credentials under the `pyspark/conf` folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your issue is https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ca-certificates-java/+bug/1739631, you might want to try the workaround from https://gist.github.com/mikaelhg/527204e746984cf9a33f7910bb8b4cb6, which is

```
/usr/bin/printf '\xfe\xed\xfe\xed\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\xe2\x68\x6e\x45\xfb\x43\xdf\xa4\xd9\x92\xdd\x41\xce\xb6\xb2\x1c\x63\x30\xd7\x92' > /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts

/var/lib/dpkg/info/ca-certificates-java.postinst configure
```

Comment: I have no idea what that did but it worked like a charm. Thank you very much!
I just have one question: I noticed that in the gist you posted the first line is missing (`echo "storepass=''" etc`). I used the version without this line. What is the difference?

Comment: Oh, and to save some time for other beginners like me: to avoid permission problems, you should copy the lines into a `.sh` file and run it with `sudo` privileges, then you can remove the file.

Comment: The two-line workaround is simpler and thus better. I just didn't think of it first. I'll edit this answer to include the better solution.